# C# - Improving a Multi-Threaded Application Design

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture, multithreading

#### Specification

- C# Distributed Application.
- Client/Server design.
- Client (Winforms), Server (Windows Service), Communication via .Net Remoting.
- The below question relates to the **Server-Side** of the application.
- ***(EDIT)*** The **Server-side** of the application runs on a server with **8 Cores** and **12Gb Ram**
- ***(EDIT)*** The **CPU** of this server is always hitting around **80% Usage** due to lots of other services being run on this same server.

#### Scenario

- I've inheritted a large legacy application.
- It carries out a bunch of tasks, some of them independently, but others not.
- The current design for this application involves the creation of 14 threads, each running either 1 task or a number of tasks.
- The problem is that I get the feeling this design element has an impact on **performance**.

#### Code Examples - How Each Class/Thread Is Designed & Run

```
public class ManageThreads
{
    private Thread doStuffThread = null;

    //Inside the constructor EVERY thread is instantiated and run.
    //(I am aware that this example only shows the use of 1 thread).
    public ManageThreads()
    {
       doStuffThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoSomeStuff.Instance.Start));
       doStuffThread.Start();

       //Instantiate and run another thread.....
       //Instantiate and run another thread.....
       //Instantiate and run another thread.....etc.
    }

}

public class DoSomeStuff
{
    void Start()
    { 
        while(true)
        {
          //Repeatedly do some tasks.....

          Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
     }   
 }
```

#### Thoughts

- What I'd like to do is keep the existing code, but modify the way that it runs.
- I've thought about the use of a **Thread Pool** to solve this problem, but given the current architecture I am unsure of how I would go about doing this.

#### Questions

- Would this current design affect performance in a noticeable way?
- Is it possible for me to improve the performance of this application without altering the underlying functions, but changing the design slightly?
- Can anyone recommend anything / advise me on the right way to go about improving this?

Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you have hyper-threading and quad-core CPU, it is like having 8 logical processors, you should `ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads=7`. If the work is *reactive*, you'll probably have some `if (shouldWork) work` in your `DoSomeStuff` and you probably set `shouldWork=true` somewhere in your application (pseudoCode). You could do `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` indead of `shouldWork=true`. It may require a wrapper.

Comment: I see your edit, then you probably have 16 logical CPUs at your disposal so context switching should not occur much (unless you are already running many threads). You probably won't see much performace difference in a `ThreadPool` version of your application (profile your application to identify your performance problems).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "I get the feeling this design element has an impact on performance."

Don't guess, get a profiler out and measure what's going on.  Gather some empirical stats about where time is spent in the application and then you can take a  view on where the pinch points are.

If the time spent creating threads is your biggest headache then moving to a threadpool *may* be the right answer, but you won't know without some forensic analysis.

From the small snippet you've posted it looks like the 14 threads are reasonably long-lived, doing multiple things over their lifetime so I suspect that this is not the problem actually, but there isn't enough info in your post to make a definitive call on this.

Comment: So you're suggesting that even though there are 14 threads running constantly, the actual code inside the classes may just be terrible and thus causing the application to run slowly?

Comment: It's entirely possible.  Note if they all have a Thread.Sleep(5000) they aren't running constantly either.

Answer (score 0):

if your threads are all doing work and you have more threads active than processors then you are going to be spending time context switching.

If you have a dual core processor dont expect to get great performance with more than 4 active working threads.

So starting off 14 threads that are all doing work is a bad idea unless you have a processor that can manage this. Physical processor architecture  and feature set has a big impacrt on this. My point is that a threadpool will help manage the context switching but starting 14 busy threads at once is always gonna kill performance ... you will probably get faster performance from simply excuting the threads sequentially. Obviously that is a big statement and so is probably not trus, but you get the gist.

Hence the use of a thread pool along with a profiler to figure out the optimum number of threads to make available to the thread pool.

In most situations when people are usign a thread pool a lot of the threads are doing nothing most of the time, or a thread is sleeping/blocking whilst some slow operation or external dependancy awaits a response.

consider using an asynch pattern so that you can get info about progress out of your threads.

On a dual core processor i would be hesitant abou tusing more than 3 threads if they are all working 100% of the time

Comment: - I've added some information about the server to the start of the question.

Comment: a rough rule of thumb i have found is that each processor can cope with about 2 threads ... but this is specific to core duo architecture that i use at home where I ahve tested. You really need to do the experiements ... there is nothing better than empirical evidence - the threadpool was pretty much designed for this.